# Add remote validation only on changed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been trying to get this done on jquery validation plugin, i tried almost all answers i found.

But none worked , so i wrote the script myself but it still didnt work :/

Problem :
**Email duplication check stucks due to user's own email**

What i did is :

I wrote a function that binds a function to each element with EmailValid class.
That binded function checks if the value is the default value , if so removes remote rule,
else adds remote rule.
I also run that "default value checking function" at document ready state.

```
<input type="hidden" id="Email_default" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" />
<input type="textbox" class="emailValid" id="Email" name="Email" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" /></td>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".emailValid").each(
    function()
    {
        rules.rules[$(this).attr("id")]=
        {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/checkmail"
        };
        rules.messages[$(this).attr("id")]=
        {
            required:"Please enter a valid email address",
            email:"Please enter a valid email address",
            remote:"This email address is already registered"
        };
        $("#editForm").validate(rules);
        setRemoteValidation(this);
        $(this).change(
        function()
        {
            setRemoteValidation(this);
        });
    });
});
var rules={
rules:{},
messages:{}
};
function setRemoteValidation(el)
{
    if($("#"+$(el).attr("id")+"_default").val()!=$(el).val())
    {
        $(el).rules("add", {
         rules:         {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/checkmail"
        },
         messages: {
            required:"Please enter a valid email address",
            email:"Please enter a valid email address",
            remote:"This email address is already registered"
        }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(el).rules("remove","remote");
    }
}
</script>
```